# How to escape HTML in Rails but avoid link tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss, html-escape-characters

ex. I have content like this

> @nash_su   blablablabla

The @nash_su is convert to link when the content is created. And before convert I escape the content for security reason.

But when user edit the content , for security reason I have to escape the content again, but this will escape the @nash_su link.

So my question is: How to avoid escape link tag?

Comment: try to express your question in different way, with real examples where and what you render/parse or want to...

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [auto_link gem](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink)

```
auto_link("Visit http://www.loudthinking.com/ or e-mail david@loudthinking.com", :link => :email_addresses)
# => "Visit http://www.loudthinking.com/ or e-mail <a href=\"mailto:david@loudthinking.com\">david@loudthinking.com</a>"
```